# Calling method with "keyEventArgs" as argument

Tags: c#, winforms, invoke, keyeventargs

I have 2 questions.

1. The first main question is how do I fix the error I have when trying to invoke the method that contain `KeyEventArgs e` as argument. I only know how to deal with arguments when they are variables.
2. The Second is just a quick question if the `while` loop will do so the program wait for (keydown) before printing the text(label)

   ```
   namespace Test2014
   {
       public partial class Form1 : Form
       {
           List<Action> methods = new List<Action>();

           public Form1()
           {
               InitializeComponent();

               // 1. Error invalid arguments
               methods.Insert(0, test); // 1.  passing ( KeyEventArgs e ) as argument ?

           }

           private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               methods[0].Invoke();

           }


           void test(KeyEventArgs e) // 1. passing ( KeyEventArgs e ) as argument ?
           {          
               while (true) 
               {

                   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)  // 2. do this work as wait for keydown before moving down ?
                       break;

               } // 2.
               label_test.Text = "When Loop is broken (key down(A)) change this label";
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Don't use `while (true)` in the event handler.  It will loop indefinitely unless the right key is pressed.

Comment: @DStanley Isn't that the point?

Comment: @BenAaronson I think D Stanley meant by that that an event driven approach might be better. From my experience such loops will take at least 50% CPU time even if there's nothing to be processed in it other than this if block.

Comment: @FrancisDucharme Yeah, I was assuming this was more of a toy example than anything else, but I guess it *is* worth emphasising that it's not a good approach in a real application

Comment: Can we have the definition of `test` that you are trying to add to the list and later call its `Invoke` method?

Comment: @BenAaronson If `test` is called and passed a key _other_ than "A" the function will loop indefinitely and the program will "hang".  The OP seems to think that he/she is setting up a "message loop" that will infinitely loop and only respond if the right key is pressed.  That's not what's happening here - control is never passed back to the calling method.